# SwipeRefreshLayout is reducing the size my views after each refresh

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

Within my `RecyclerView` I am using `SwipeRefreshLayout`.
The refresh works fine and I get the refreshed data, but the images within `SwipeRefreshLayout` (`CardView`, `TextViews`, `ImageViews`,..) are getting smaller and smaller with each new refresh.

**XML LAYOUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.rssreader.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img_fb"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="57dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/facebook_icon2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/img_mail"
        android:src="@mipmap/mail_icon"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_fb"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_fb"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/img_fb" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java, RefreshListener class:**

```
private class MyRefreshListener implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            new ReadRss(getContext(),recyclerView).execute();


        }
    }
```

**SCREENSHOTS:**

[image: Scaled size]

[image: Original size]

Any ideas guys ? cant figure it out.

Comment: please, post a few screenshots of effect you got

Comment: It sounds like you were setting padding/margin of recycler view each time you load new content (on code)

Comment: added screenshots.
@MarioVelasco Mario I thought the same, but I didn't set it, atleast not intentional. But it looks like some margin, yes.

Comment: please post `ReadRss`

Comment: @g2o it's a bit long code, but you gave a good hint! in there I use some view manipulation onPostExecute, will check ! THANKS FOR TIP!

Answer (score 2):

**Thanks to @g20 and @MarioVelasco who pointed me to right direction, I solved this issue.**

**ANSWER:**

> The issue was that inside my `XmlParser`, I was setting some Layout
>   parameters. So `onRefresh()` executed also then `XmlParser`, and some
>   Margins were added additionally and again for each refresh.
>
> I moved those parameters outside of my `XmlParser` class to more
>   appropriate place (for e.g. in `MainActivity` after initializing the
>   `RecyclerView`) and now it works as it should.

Comment: Hi David, can you tell me where exactly were these parameters? I am facing the same issue. I am not setting any parameters, and where should we make the changes  exactly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can remove your RelativeLayout. maybe help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.rssreader.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_fb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="57dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/facebook_icon2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_mail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_fb"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_fb"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/img_fb"
        android:src="@mipmap/mail_icon" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Hi reza, thanks for your post, but we figured it out on a bit different way. It seemed that I was changing some Margins in a bad place in code, so on each execute I also refreshed the margins of my layouts, so they were shrinking more and more.

Your answer might also work, but I will post as accepted answer the one that helped me without removing anything from code. 

Thanks though!